# Calculate time based upon distance

Tags: ios, swift, physics, game-physics

I'm sure this is basic physics, but how can I calculate the time it should take to travel a specific distance, based upon a constant speed. For example, I have view A and view B. View A needs to move up the screen by 20 pixels. View B needs to move up the screen by 50 pixels. How can I calculate how long it takes to move that distance at a specific speed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity

Comment: It's just basic division... Velocity `v = 10 px/s`, distance `d = 20 px`, time `t = d / v = 2 sec`.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry I've actually found the answer:

```
time = distance / speed
```

Quite simple in the end :P